# Learn Python the Hard Way - ex.23: Why does it only show one line?

Tags: python, powershell, utf-8

Trying to read python (and anything programming related) for the first time now with Zed A. Shaw's book "Learn Python the Hard Way" and got stuck in exercise 23 with a problem for which I did not find an answer online.

I wrote the code as shown in the book:

```py
import sys
script, encoding, error = sys.argv

def main(language_file, encoding, errors):
    line = language_file.readline()

    if line:
        print_line(line,encoding,errors)
        return (main, language_file, encoding, errors)

def print_line(line, encoding, errors):
    next_lang= line.strip()
    raw_bytes = next_lang.encode(encoding, errors=errors)
    cooked_string = raw_bytes.decode(encoding, errors=errors)

    print(raw_bytes, "<===>", cooked_string)

languages = open("languages.txt", encoding="UTF-8")

main(languages, encoding, error)
```

[as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqN4r.png)

But when running it on Powershell, it only displays the first line:

```
PS C:\Usuários\Saulo\Python> python ex23.py utf-8 script
b'\xef\xbb\xbfAfrikaans' <===> Afrikaans
PS C:\Usuários\Saulo\Python>
```

[as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiBoK.png)

I've tried in on cmd but got the same result.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you are only reading the line once. You need a loop to read all lines

Comment: Are you sure it's supposed to be `(main, ...)` instead of `main(...)`?

Comment: Please (also) post your code, data, error messages as ([properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)) _text_, [not (just) as _images_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/45375).

Comment: If that's the code, get a new book.  It has bad habits like opening a file without closing it (or using `with`) and recursively calling main when a `for` or `while` loop would be more appropriate.

Comment: Use `open("languages.txt", encoding="utf_8_sig")`. [On decoding, an optional UTF-8 encoded BOM at the start of the data will be skipped.](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/codecs.html#module-encodings.utf_8_sig)

Answer (score 0):

Samwise is right. You have a typo in your code. Line 9 supposed to be:

```
return main(language_file, encoding, errors)
```